# How to debug a custom loss function?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I don't have a specific problem at the moment, but it keeps coming up that I have a bug in my loss function and the error printouts are not sufficient to localize the problem to a specific line of code.  For example `expected 'int32' but got 'float32'` or something like that. Is there a way to know which line of code in the loss function is the source of the problem?

I'll note that sometimes the error comes during compilation, in which case print statements have been helpful. But I have not identified a way to find the problem (outside of guessing or commenting out sections) if it happens only during training, since printouts are not displayed.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote.  I suppose the problem is that I didn't post a specific problem so you could just point out the error instead of answering the question I'm actually asking.

Comment: If there is an error like the one you mentioned, usually you get a larger error message, which at one point should normally give you the exact line in which the error happens. Is that not the case for you?

Comment: No, the stack all points to internal Tensorflow code.  I think it can't point back to my code because it has been compiled and the error happens later, such as during a fit.

Comment: Make sure to check the stack further down the line. Often, the last 10 or 20 entries point to tensorflow code and the further up something for your own code is displayed. If this is not the case, often at least the type of operation (like multiplication, etc.) is displayed, so that you can at least try to understand it this way. If you get an error message for which this does not apply, maybe try to add it to this comment so that others can try to help you with that.

Comment: And for errors during a fit call, you mentioned that print statements help. This should often be enough to get a rough idea of what could have gone wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of following option to debug custom loss function or any other deep learning works.

1. [tf.print](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate/migration_debugging)
2. [tfbdg](https://developers.googleblog.com/2017/02/debug-tensorflow-models-with-tfdbg.html)
3. [TensorBoard debugger](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/debugger_v2)